# Syntax error with Stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement Stripe on my web application and I am having a problem setting the API key

Here is my code:

```
<?php //composer autoloader require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
 $stripe = [
    'publishable' =>'pk_test(public code))',
    'private' => 'sk_test(private code)' ]

   Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['private']);
     // \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['private']);
?>
```

I have tried both methods and none seems to work.  I keep getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\stripe_test\app\init.php on line 12

Comment: No semicolon after your array.

Comment: Hint for "unexpected X" type parse errors: if there's something unexpected on one line, check the line _before it_. It's unexpected because it doesn't know you're done giving it the previous instruction.

Comment: Thanks!. I just noticed that

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a `;`

```
$stripe = [
    'publishable' =>'pk_test(public code))',
    'private' => 'sk_test(private code)' ]; // added ; here
```